# Get Connection String automatically in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I've connected a database file (made from SQL Server .mdf) to one of my C# program. But when I take those files to another PC I need to give the connection string again. It's very annoying for me.

Is there any way to get that connection string automatically when I move my project files to another PC?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't think so this is possible.When you transfer you visual studio solution from one pc to another you have to manually change the connection string either in web.config file or in the c# code.There's no way visual studio can automatically detect the database installed on a particular pc and get the connectionstring from it

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Possible.

Suppose Your Project name is MYproject.

So Please put your database in the Follwing path
**D:\Projects\MYproject\MYproject.UI\bin\Debug\Database\sql.mdf**.

Change your connection string like below

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBNAME" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\..\..\..\MYproject.UI\bin\Debug\Database\sql.mdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```